# How to Route User After Form Validation In React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I'm New To React And Trying To make SignUp SignIn Project.

I'm Trying To Route User To Login / SignIn Page If From Validation Success.

this is my SignUp code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Axios from 'axios';

const initianValue = {
  username: '',
  password: '',
  nameError: '',
  passError: '',
  dataError: '',
};

class SignUp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = initianValue;
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  validForm() {
    let nameError = '';
    let passError = '';
    let dataError = '';

    const user = {
      username: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password,
    };

    if (!this.state.username) {
      nameError = 'Enter Name';
    }

    if (user.username !== '' && user.password !== '') {
      Axios.post('http://localhost:9000/checkUser', user)
        .then((res) => this.setState({ dataError: res.data }))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }

    if (!this.state.password) {
      passError = 'Enter Password';
    }

    if (nameError || passError || dataError) {
      this.setState({
        nameError,
        passError,
        dataError,
      });
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const isvalid = this.validForm();
    if (isvalid) {
      this.setState(initianValue, () => this.props.history.push('/Signin'));
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='Main'>
        <span className='create'>Create Account</span>
        <div className='SignUp'>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className='form-group'>
              <label>Username</label>
              <input
                type='text'
                name='username'
                value={this.state.username}
                className='form-control'
                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
              />
              <div className='error'>
                {this.state.nameError}
                {this.state.dataError}
              </div>
              <br />
              <label>Password</label>
              <input
                type='password'
                name='password'
                value={this.state.password}
                className='form-control'
                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
              />
              <div className='error'>{this.state.passError}</div>
              <br />

              <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'>
                Sign Up
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div className='signinForm'>
          <label>
            Already Have Account <Link to='/Signin'> Sign In </Link>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SignUp;
```

This Is SignUp From And After Completing this From If No Errors I want To Send User to SignIn Page Or Next Page.

Should I Use Redux ?

How Can I Do That ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `SignUp` component is wrapped inside `Router` your component should already have access to `history` using `props.

So you can simply do this `this.props.history.push`. Use the 2nd arg in `setState` which is a fun which gets executed after setting state (as setState is async)

**Like this**

```js
handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const isvalid = this.validForm();
  if (isvalid) {
    this.setState(initianValue, () => this.props.history.push("/dashboard"));//<----- like this
  }
};
```

If your `SignUp` component is not inside of `Router` then you can use [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter). Just pass `Signup` to withRouter hoc.

Comment: First I Need To Install History module ?

Comment: not reqd in your case... try that and let me know if issues...also share your router configuration code (if u face issue)

Comment: Its Works On Currect Input but When In Put Wrong Username or Password It Shows Worning On Console Like This ?

Comment: index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in SignUp (created by Context.Consumer)

Comment: And Also I Install history Module But Its Showing history is define But Never used

Comment: updated the ans & code snippet.... And Just remove importing the `history`.... in the line of code `import { Link, history } from 'react-router-dom';` , just remove `history`.. you will be fine.

Comment: ok - you have just removed history import (which is fine) ... but you need to also update the `handleSubmit` as well (as per my updated answer's code snippet) ... you need to do history.push inside setState callback ...

Comment: as is say its works fine on right input but in wrong username or password im getting warning in console like this " Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in SignUp (created by Context.Consumer) "

Comment: umm okay ...I got the issue .. it is an un-related topic to this qn actually ... can u pls open a new qn ... simply paste the code snippet(updated code snippet as per my ans) and say below code is producing this error...asking good qns also improves your reputation ... i will quickly answer your new qn (or some other SO user will answer anyway...)

Comment: Okay So I'm Doing Another Question

Comment: yes...pls do that... SO is also about helping ourselves and helping others also ... your new issue is a good one and it might help others also

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62737500/12598445 this is link @gdh

Answer (score 0):

We can use `<Redirect/>` component form react-router-dom to redirect the page in the following way

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const isvalid = this.validForm();
  if (isvalid) {
    this.setState(initianValue, () => <Redirect to='/dashboard' />);
};
```